# Numbering Pages with number other than 1 in wicked_pdf

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I'm having a bad time on doing this. As in the docs of `wicked_pdf` it is written to use `js` to custom numbering of page if it has `page-breaks`.

As my `pdf` is continuous I used `controller` option to provide numbering

```
header: {font_size: 7, right: "Page " "[page] of [topage]" }
```

I tried to add the custom numbering by adding string interpolation at `page` but that's can never work as the `page` is taken by js.

Please help me out with this. Thank You.

Comment: What is the expected behavior?

Comment: Hello adelin, so if I provide a number 5 while generating pdf it should start numbering the page from 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this [reference](https://github.com/prakashmurthy/wicked-pdf-sample-app/blob/master/vendor/plugins/wicked_pdf/README.md) there is an option of `page_offset` when rendering the pdf